# Get image from JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

I tried to get Image from JSON. Imagedata is printing in the console. But its displaying in the UITableViewCell.

```
jsonDict = [jsonArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

NSLog(@"imagess%@",jsonDict);

```
cell.textLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageName"];
cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]];
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

The code I've used to Post the image:

```
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put a debugger pointer on `NSURL *url` and check whether it is initialized or, not, I guess it is `nil`, and if it is `nil` so your image url might need `string encoding`. By the way your question doesn't state anything not working, I am just guessing your image doesn't display.

Comment: have u check NSURL *url contains value or not

Comment: ya its null @iphonic. just i checked it

Comment: what is your image URL in console please give me.

Comment: NSLog(@"imagess%@",jsonDict);, in this place u were getting the image result

Comment: i am getting the jsondata as it is with NSLog(@"imagess%@",jsonDict);.  once check my question i just edited it @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: actually u were getting the image url, k in cell,image view.image in this line before u were adding the your server path //url/9j/....

Comment: your coding is fine, but in my knowledge u were not adding the correct path of the server where u get the image

Comment: [my webservices link](http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/GetUnAnsweredImagesLog?UserId=72) check this link in ur pc once @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

As per you data log, it seems that you have got the whole image there in `imageData` key. And that looks to me as if it is `base64 encoded`.

You don't need to use and `URL`, you need a base64 decoder, that will convert your base64 encoded string to `NSData`.

Please confirm with api team, whether it is encoded for `Base64` or, not.

Take Base64 lib for iOS from [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

And you just need to do the following

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

Cheers.

Comment: your answer is very closer to the solution.

Comment: There must be an endpoint url using which you are fetching json, use that, or to append with actual `image url` you have.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper No wait it looks something different, check my update, once.

Comment: i got error no known class method for 'dataWithBase64EncodedString'

Comment: You have to `#import "Base64.h"`after adding this library https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it may help you

Here **imageurl** is the address of the image u will accessed for JSON and Image url like http:/google/123.png   and in this example **cell** is the UITableView Cell used in my app.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageurl];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   cell.imagePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

                               }

                           }];
```

Thanks